# Changing color causes memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, colors

I am writing a very useful program. This function changes colors of some items of the form. Once it starts the memory of the program is increasing in task manager. How could I fix that?

```
private void Autism_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
                dgv_fak.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
                RTB_info.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
                menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));

                for (int i = 0; i < dgv_fak.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dgv_fak.ColumnCount; j++)
                    {
                        dgv_fak.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
                    }
                }
                dgv_fak.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256), rng.Next(1, 256));
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an actual leak going on? In C#, the Garbage Collector takes care of allocating and freeing memory.

Comment: I use it but this function doesn't make things better. It continues to use more and more memory. It saves every single color there.

Comment: Use a memory profiler and trace the leaked objects to their GC roots.